# Overlay a graph over a Video

Tags: python, matplotlib, ffmpeg

Is there a solution to open a mp4 and overlay a graph (Matplotlib) or something like this?

Something like [this](http://www.cbcity.de/datenvisualisierung-mit-matlab)

Answer (score 4):

You can obtain the frames from the video using openCV, as in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18954889/how-to-process-images-of-a-video-frame-by-frame-in-video-streaming-using-opencv), and plot a graph over the top with matplotlib, e.g.

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

filename = './SampleVideo.mp4'
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(filename)

try:
    frames = int(cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
    width  = int(cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
    height = int(cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
except AttributeError:
    frames = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
    width  = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
    height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
plt.ion()
plt.show()

#Setup a dummy path
x = np.linspace(0,width,frames)
y = x/2. + 100*np.sin(2.*np.pi*x/1200)

for i in range(frames):
    fig.clf()
    flag, frame = cap.read()

    plt.imshow(frame)
    plt.plot(x,y,'k-', lw=2)
    plt.plot(x[i],y[i],'or')
    plt.pause(0.01)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
        break
```

I got the video from [here](https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4).

Comment: I got your example working.  How would I go about saving the video file with the graphs drawn on it?

Comment: Hi @tylerjw, you could use cv2 `VideoWriter` or `matplotlib` `manimation` writer. Personally I'd save frames to file and then build a video from images, using `savefig('./out{:05d}'.format(i).png` to get a range of file with successive names and then put together with `ffmpeg` or something...

Comment: Thank you.  I found that matplotlib is just too slow for my application(not real time, but faster than several seconds/frame) so I'm going to try to write it using opencv and their drawing tools.

Comment: The site of the video has a warning not to proceed from my browser ;(

Comment: Hi @KansaiRobot, just updated link

Comment: somehow it doesn't work. `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'cv'`. I modified it to `cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT`. However I don't see neither plot or video

Comment: I tried to modify it. Didn't work :(

Comment: Looks like cv has changed, added exception handle

Comment: Hi @KansaiRobot, does it work now it's updated?

Comment: I have run it quickly and it seems it works. Sorry I will check it better in the weekend

Comment: I am wondering if there is a way to not only show it but also putting back into a video format. (so that it can be played later)

Answer (score 0):

I find the python script in [this blog](https://www.learnpythonwithrune.org/insert-live-graph-in-webcam-stream-using-webcam-with-opencv/) as a good alternate way of drawing graph using OpenCV without using matplotlib which would be slow as mentioned by [tylerjw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2320513/tylerjw) in the comments for the answer by [Ed Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4680533/ed-smith)

I have made modifications from my side in the Graph class defined in the script provided in [the blog](https://www.learnpythonwithrune.org/insert-live-graph-in-webcam-stream-using-webcam-with-opencv/) by aligning x-axis with frame-count and using cv2.line() instead of filling numpy array with white color:

> 

```
class Graph:
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.graph = np.zeros((height, width, 3), np.uint8)
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
    def update_frame(self, value, frame_count):
        if value < 0:
            value = 0
        elif value >= self.height:
            value = self.height - 1
        new_graph = np.zeros((self.height, self.width, 3), np.uint8)
        new_graph[:,:-1,:] = self.graph[:,1:,:]

        # cv2.line(self.graph, (self.y, self.x), (value, frame_count//1000), (0, 0, 255))
    cv2.line(new_graph, (self.x, self.y), (frame_count//10, value), (0, 0, 255))

    self.x = frame_count // 10
    self.y = value

    # new_graph[self.height - value:self.height - value + 5,-1,:2] = 0
    # new_graph[self.height - value:self.height - value + 5,-1,2] = 255
    self.graph = new_graph
def get_graph(self):
    return self.graph

# Setup camera
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
# Set a smaller resolution
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480)
graph = Graph(100, 60)
prev_frame = np.zeros((480, 640), np.uint8)
frame_count = 0
while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        break
    frame_count += 1
    frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (640, 480))
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (25, 25), None)
    diff = cv2.absdiff(prev_frame, gray)
    difference = np.sum(diff)
    prev_frame = gray
    graph.update_frame(int(difference/42111), frame_count)
    roi = frame[-70:-10, -110:-10,:]
    roi[:] = graph.get_graph()
    cv2.putText(frame, "...wanted a live graph", (20, 430), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1.8, (0, 200, 200), 2)
    cv2.putText(frame, "...measures motion in frame", (20, 460), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1.8, (0, 200, 200), 2)
    cv2.imshow("Webcam", frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

> 