# How to create array of frames from an mp4 with opencv for python

Tags: python, opencv, video

I am attempting to use opencv_python to break an mp4 file down into it's frames so I can later open them with pillow, or at least be able to use the images to run my own methods on them.

I understand that the following snippet of code gets a frame from a live video or a recorded video.

```
    import cv2
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture("myfile.mp4")
    boolean, frame = cap.read()
```

What exactly does the read function return and how can I create an array of images which I can modify.

Comment: see: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html

Comment: see also http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html

Comment: Thanks for the links, but this does not answer my question. My goal is to actually store these images in an array without using disk space.

Answer (score 1):

adapted from [How to process images of a video, frame by frame, in video streaming using OpenCV and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18954889/how-to-process-images-of-a-video-frame-by-frame-in-video-streaming-using-opencv). Untested. However, the frames are read into a numpy array and and append to a list that is converted to a numpy array when the all the frames are read in.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


images = []

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("./out.mp4")
while not cap.isOpened():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture("./out.mp4")
    cv2.waitKey(1000)
    print "Wait for the header"

pos_frame = cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)
while True:
    frame_ready, frame = cap.read() # get the frame
    if frame_ready:
        # The frame is ready and already captured
        # cv2.imshow('video', frame)

        # store the current frame in as a numpy array
        np_frame = cv2.imread('video', frame)
        images.append(np_frame)
        
        pos_frame = cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)
    else:
        # The next frame is not ready, so we try to read it again
        cap.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, pos_frame-1)
        print "frame is not ready"
        # It is better to wait for a while for the next frame to be ready
        cv2.waitKey(1000)

    if cv2.waitKey(10) == 27:
        break
    if cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES) == cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT):
        # If the number of captured frames is equal to the total number of frames,
        # we stop
        break

all_frames = np.array(images)
```

Comment: thank you very much. Thank you for commenting out the code. I love to have a good understanding of it

Comment: no problem, glad I could help. If it worked consider marking it as the answer.

Comment: hey, I have a small issue.

Comment: np_frame = cv2.imread('video', frame) returns this error and I have no idea what to do:

Comment: TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Comment: `cv2.imread('video', frame)` throws TypeError: 'flags' is required to be an integer

Comment: @preneond how did you work on flags should be an integer? I am facing it too

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this code to get an array of frames from your video:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
frames = []
video = cv2.VideoCapture("spiderino_turning.mp4")
while True:
    read, frame= video.read()
    if not read:
        break
    frames.append(frame)
frames = np.array(frames)
```

but regarding your question, `video.read()` returns two values. The first one (`read` in the example code) indicates if the frame is successfully read or not (i.e., `True` on succeeding and `False` on any error). The second returning value is the frame that can be empty if the read attempt is unsuccessful or a 3D array (i.e., color image) otherwise.
But why can a read attempt be unsuccessful?

1. If you are reading from a camera, any problem with the camera (e.g., the cable is disconnected or the camera's battery is dead) can cause an error.
2. If you are reading from a video, the read attempt will fail when all the frames are read, and there are no more.