# How to read video files using python & Opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I am reading an avi file usinh python 2.7 and opencv2.4.I am using windows 10.My sample code is

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('videos/wa.avi')
while(cap.isOpened()):
  ret, frame = cap.read()
  gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
  if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

When i run video is shown But the program ends with no Error

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in cv::imshow, file ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp, line 261
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Emmanu/PycharmProjects/VideoEventDetection/test.py", line 11, in <module>
cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
cv2.error: ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:261: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow
```

What i am doing wrong?How can i correct it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

This line expects frame to be a 3 channel or 4 channel Mat object but instead it got some empty Mat and that is why you are getting this assertion failed. 
You need to check if the frame exists in video and need to handle end of video properly.

`cap.isOpened()` will just check if the video file can be opened for reading but it will not return a false when end of video file is reached.

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19082750/2752983)

Comment: FIle doesn't open for me. opencv version 3.0.0 beta. Any suggestions?

Comment: Thank you for replying but I don't remember the issue now but I think it was resolved after I installed opencv-ffmpeg again

Answer (score 1):

When you put `cap.isOpened()` it check that, the video is read properly, So the `while` loop is not working there.

But when you changed to `while True` it will execute without proper reading that's why it's giving an error.

> Make sure than you are properly reading the video file.

Comment: you are right,there was a problem with video.When i changed the video and run it with 'cap.isOpened()'.Video shown up thanks for that but program end with an error.I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

You took the tutorial from here: [Playing Video from file](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html#playing-video-from-file)

This question adresses your error: [open cv error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30506126/open-cv-error-215-scn-3-scn-4-in-function-cvtcolor)

Two things may work:

- Make sure the video is found!
- And try to use `cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)`

Comment: Yes there was a problem with video file.I have updated the question

Comment: Try to use `cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB` instead of `cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY`

Answer (score 0):

Well I am guessing the capture is not open. That's why your program ends instantly when you use `while(cap.isOpened()):`.

As stated in this [doc](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html#capture-video-from-camera) it happens that the capture is not implicitly opened when created.

> Sometimes, cap may not have initialized the capture. In that case, this code shows error. You can check whether it is initialized or not by the method cap.isOpened(). If it is True, OK. Otherwise open it using cap.open().

Try to explicitly open the capture like so :

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('videos/wa.avi')
cap.open();
while(cap.isOpened()):
...
```

If this does not work you will have to check for the video file path.

Comment: Yes there was a problem with video file.I have updated the question